# VBScript to Automate Outlook emails via Mail Merge

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, outlook

Im looking for a VBScript that will automatically send an email to each person on a list of contacts I have in an excel tabel using a mail merge.

Any help would be much appreciated and if you need more info just ask :)

Basically I have this code

```
Sub SendMessage(DisplayMsg As Boolean, Optional AttachmentPath)
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

  ' Create the Outlook session.
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  ' Create the message.
  Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  With objOutlookMsg
      ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
      Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Nancy Davolio")
      objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

     ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
     .Subject = "This is an Automation test with Microsoft Outlook"
     .Body = "This is the body of the message." &vbCrLf & vbCrLf
     .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance

     ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
     For Each ObjOutlookRecip In .Recipients
         objOutlookRecip.Resolve
     Next

     ' Should we display the message before sending?
     If DisplayMsg Then
         .Display
     Else
         .Save
         .Send
     End If
  End With
  Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

But I need it to, instead of creating an email, it uses a mail merge, and the email is to be sent to everyone on a list stored in an excel sheet, problem is, I have no idea how to do this so any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will send one email to each person listed in an excel file. For this example, the name is in column A, the email address is in column B and the subject is in column C. Create a template in the drafts folder and set the subject to "Template". In the template email, use {} around any field you want to replace with another. In this example, {name} is replaced with the name from column A. Insert the {image} tag where you want the image to go. I'm assuming you want the same image since it's a corporate logo, so you just define the path in the SendMessage Sub. This will add the image as an attachment, there is no easy way to get around that but it will be embedded into the body of the email.

```
set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open ("H:\Book1.xls")
'skip header row. set to 1 if you
'don't have a header row
set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
row = 2
name = sh.Range("A" & row)
email = sh.Range("B" & row)
subject = sh.Range("C" & row)
'image = sh.Range("D" & row)
LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For r = row to LastRow
    If App.WorkSheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows(r)) <> 0 Then 
        SendMessage email, name, subject, TRUE, _
        NULL, "H:\Scripts\Batch\pic.png", 80,680
        row = row + 1
        name = sh.Range("A" & row)
        email = sh.Range("B" & row)
        subject = sh.Range("C" & row)
        'image = sh.Range("D" & row)
    End if
Next
wb.close
set wb = nothing
set app = nothing


Sub SendMessage(EmailAddress, DisplayName, Subject, DisplayMsg, AttachmentPath, ImagePath, ImageHeight, ImageWidth)

  ' Create the Outlook session.
  Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  template = FindTemplate()

  ' Create the message.
  Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

  With objOutlookMsg
      ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
      Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(EmailAddress)
      objOutlookRecip.resolve
      objOutlookRecip.Type = 1

     ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
     .Subject = Subject
     .bodyformat = 3
     .Importance = 2  'High importance
     body = Replace(template, "{name}", DisplayName)

     if not isNull(ImagePath) then
       if not ImagePath = "" then
         .Attachments.add ImagePath
         image = split(ImagePath,"\")(ubound(split(ImagePath,"\")))
         body = Replace(body, "{image}", "<img src='cid:" & image & _
         "'" & " height=" & ImageHeight &" width=" & ImageWidth & ">")
       end if
     else
        body = Replace(body, "{image}", "")
     end if

     if not isNull(AttachMentPath) then
       .Attachments.add AttachmentPath
     end if

     .HTMLBody = body

     ' Should we display the message before sending?
     If DisplayMsg Then
         .Display
     Else
         .Save
         .Send
     End If
    End With
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub

Function FindTemplate()
    Set OL = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
    set Drafts = OL.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(16)
    Set oItems = Drafts.Items

    For Each Draft In oItems
        If Draft.subject = "Template" Then
            FindTemplate = Draft.HTMLBody
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks alot, another query for you: Is it possible to use this script to mail merge info stored on the same excel table with a template and send it?

Comment: It doesn't like the 'Rows' part of the following                    For r = row to LastRow step 1
    If App.CountA(Rows(r)) <> 0 Then 
        SendMessage email, name, "Here you go","This is the body of the Message", 0
        row = row + 1
        name = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row)
        mail = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row)
    End if
Next

Comment: I fixed the Rows error and updated the code to use a template. Enjoy

Comment: Is it possible to add a company logo into the template as when I do it just appears a white box with a red X in it?

Comment: Yeah. You can't just add it to the Template file because the code is being generated. You have to use code to do it. I'll whip something up when I get a chance.

Comment: Oh, i never knew that :/ Thanks pal!

Comment: Here you go. I updated the code to insert images into the body of the email.